# Inserting/Recording data from a Userform into a database with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have been trying to insert data into my database. I keep getting an error where it isn't recognising what is set. It thinks this is invalid: `if (isset($_POST['user_email']) AND isset($_POST['user_choice'])) {` so it skips and displays my echo with the values coming through.
Here is my HTML file:

```
<?php 
require_once("../inc/config.php");

$emailAddress ="";
if(isset($_POST["user_email"])) {
    $emailAddress = trim($_POST["user_email"]);
  $newsletter = trim($_POST["emailLetter"]);
  if($emailAddress != "") {
    require_once(ROOT_PATH . "inc/images.php");
    $results = capture_email($emailAddress, $newsletter);
  } 
  var_dump($results);
  exit();
}
?>

  <footer id="footer-class">
  <form id="footer-form" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
      <legend id="footer-legend">Sign up for...</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="emailLetter" id="PC" value="PC" checked><label class="footerlabel" for="PC">Computer</label>
      <input type="radio" name="emailLetter" id="Photo" value="Photo"><label class="footerlabel" for="Photo">Photo</label>
      <legend id="footer-legend">Newsletter!</legend>
      <input id="footer-email" type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Enter your email address here!" required>
      <button type="submit" id="footer-button">Subscribe</button>
    </fieldset>
    <p>I won't spam you. Promise</p>
  </form>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP function:

```
<?php
function capture_email($user_email, $user_choice) {
  require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");
  if (isset($_POST['$user_email']) AND isset($_POST['$user_choice'])) {
    try {
      $newsletter = $_POST["$user_choice"];
      $email_address = $_POST["$user_email"];
      $results = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO userinfo (Email, userOption) VALUES (?, ?)");
      $results->bindparam(1, $email_address);
      $results->bindparam(2, $newsletter);
      $results->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      var_dump($e);
      exit();
    }
} else {
  echo "Oops, something went wrong. Here is the user Email: " . $user_email . "<br>Here is the user choice: " . $user_choice;
  exit();
}
}
```

Additional information: Config.php is a file containing variables for the database connection. images.php is a file where I store all my php functions.
Please let me know if you need anymore information.
Thanks

Comment: I have updated the above to show where changes were made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need to POST it. Already it is passed as an arguement.

```
 if (isset($user_email) && isset($user_choice)) {
```

You have to change full code too.

```
<?php
function capture_email($user_email, $user_choice) {
  require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");
  if (isset($user_email) AND isset($user_choice) {
    try {
      $newsletter = $user_choice;
      $email_address = $user_email;
      $results = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO userinfo (Email, userOption) VALUES (?, ?)");
      $results->bindparam(1, $email_address);
      $results->bindparam(2, $newsletter);
      $results->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      var_dump($e);
      exit();
    }
} else {
  echo "Oops, something went wrong. Here is the user Email: " . $user_email . "<br>Here is the user choice: " . $user_choice;
  exit();
}
}
```

Comment: Change it to this and a different error occurred

Notice: Undefined index: PC in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\images.php on line 130

Notice: Undefined index: nick@nick in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\images.php on line 131
object(PDOException)#3 (8) { ["message":protected]=> string(202) "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;....

Comment: Some other error occurred, so i'm 100% sure, its entering to if condition. I updated it @StackUser2014. Check it once.

Comment: I've updated it too show your changes and it comes back with an SQL syntax error: 

object(PDOException)#3 (8) { ["message":protected]=> string(202) "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> string(5) "42000" ["file":protected]=> string(30)

Comment: You have written wrong code in insert statement. I updated it. check it once @StackUser2014

Comment: Ah great! that was the issue. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer as it helped you and will help for other user to find it. Thanks. Glad to help you @StackUser2014

Answer (score 1):

I changed your function a little bit. you passing your post not your variable so it would cause a error. But this should work

```
function capture_email($user_email, $user_choice) {
  require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");

/*
*You passing the POST, but your surpose to pass thru the var from your function.
*
**/
  if (isset($user_email) AND isset($user_choice) {
    try {
      $newsletter = $user_choice;
      $email_address = $user_email;

/**
**Also Sorted your issue out with your speech mark's
**
**/

      $results = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO userinfo (Email, userOption) VALUES (?, ?)");
      $results->bindparam(1, $email_address);
      $results->bindparam(2, $newsletter);
      $results->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      var_dump($e);
      exit();
    }
} else {
  echo "Oops, something went wrong. Here is the user Email: " . $user_email . "<br>Here is the user choice: " . $user_choice;
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and re-run the code.

```
if(isset($_POST['user_email']) AND isset($_POST['user_choice'])) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition like this :

```
if (isset($user_email) AND isset($user_choice)) {
try {
      $newsletter = $user_choice;
      $email_address = $user_email;
      $results = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO userinfo (Email, userOption) VALUES (?, ?");
      $results->bindparam(1, $email_address);
      $results->bindparam(2, $newsletter);
      $results->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      var_dump($e);
      exit();
    }
}
```

Because when you calling this function capture_email(), you have passed two trimed arguments.

Answer (score -1):

there is syntax error :

```
if (isset($_POST['$user_email']) AND isset($_POST['$user_choice'])) {
```

replace with :

```
if (isset($_POST['user_email']) AND isset($_POST['user_choice'])) {
```

Update try block also :

```
try {
  $newsletter = $_POST["user_choice"];
  $email_address = $_POST["user_email"];
  $results = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO userinfo (Email, userOption) VALUES (?, ?");
  $results->bindparam(1, $email_address);
  $results->bindparam(2, $newsletter);
  $results->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  var_dump($e);
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Tried that and I am still getting the same error, it is thinks this line, ` if (isset($_POST['user_email']) && isset($_POST['user_choice'])) { ` is false so jumps to the "echo "Oops, something went wrong. Here is the user Email...." error

Comment: in your html code there is no input for "user_choice". so eithere you need to add input for that or you can remove from if condition.